# how can I convert image to icon in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

like below-
I have an icon in the navigation but I want to set the image in the icon property.

```
    BottomNavigationItem(
    icon = {
        Icon(
            imageVector = screen.icon,
            contentDescription = screen.route,
            tint = if (currentScreen ==screen ) colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary) else Color.Gray,
            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        )
    },
```

Comment: You can use painterResource instead of imageVector to use image from drawable